# How to move up the header in Twenty thirteen Revised Theme

Tags: wordpress, header

I have updated the Twenty Thirteen Revised theme in my Site and now the header has moved down. I have two sites and I have only updated one so you can see the difference. Can you help please?

http://www.secretdealshotels.com    Theme updated

http://www.secretdealsbooking.com    Theme not updated

Thank you
Fernando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace below code into class .site of style.css of your theme revised

```
margin: 60px auto;
```

to

```
margin: 0px auto;
```